# Query string parameter handling when loading a script using $.getScript

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic list of scripts that needs to be loaded and the callback function calls another async function defined in the loaded external script.

A script object consists of {scriptUrl, property}

All scripts have a externalScriptFunction function defined, that take script['property'] as a parameter.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
   var script = scripts[i];

   $.getScript(script['scriptUrl'], function() {
      externalScriptFunction(script['property'], function someAsyncMethod() {
         ...
         ...
      });

   })

}
```

The issue I am having is that before the $.getScript callback is executed, the for loop has advanced to the next element and script['property'] is from a different element of the array.

How do I solve this issue?

- Is there some way to pass a query parameter to the loaded script?
- Or a way for the $.getScript to finish loading the script before moving to the next item?
- Any other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a callback function like this,

```
var loadedCallback = function(extraData) {
    return function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        externalScriptFunction(extraData, function someAsyncMethod() {
         ...
         ...
      });
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
   var script = scripts[i];
   $.getScript(script['scriptUrl'], loadedCallback(script["property"]));

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96XDr/)

Answer (score 1):

just use closures - [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

so for your example it should look like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {

 var script = scripts[i];
 (function(script){
   $.getScript(script['scriptUrl'], function() {
      externalScriptFunction(script['property'], function someAsyncMethod() {
         ...
         ...
      });

   })
 })(script)
}
```

not sure if that code actually works, but i think you got the idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/vGgpW/